# Vaadin set Notification into certain layout

Tags: java, layout, tabs, notifications, vaadin

Does anyone know how can I set notification in Vaadin in a certain Tab or layout? I have found the code:

```
 new Notification("This is a warning",
 "<br/>This is the <i>last</i> warning",
 Notification.TYPE_WARNING_MESSAGE, true).show(Page.getCurrent());
```

But it does not work good for me, as it shows the message always on the current page `show(Page.getCurrent())`.

What I have on my page is a Tabsheet with four tabs. If users selects the 2nd tab - the Notification is needed to be shown. But at the moment with the code above it always shows the notification on the 1st Tab.

Comment: I assume the moment when you trigger the display of the notification is before the tab has actually been changed. (It's vaadin tabs and not browser tabs, correct?)

Comment: Yes, its vaadin tabs. When I open the page- it always shows the 1st tab. Notification is needed on the 2nd tab only.

Comment: When exactly do you show this notification? Are you doing this on tab change event?

Comment: Show your trigger definition